# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException

Tags: java, android, firebase

Procurei esse erro e não achei em lugar algum, apenas alguns parecidos mas não esse:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Maps with non-string keys are not supported

Controller (onde está o erro):

```
final DatabaseReference banco = db.getReference("cidade");

//Pega os dados do banco
banco.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        arrayNome.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Cidade c = data.getValue(Cidade.class);
            c.setKey(data.getKey());

            arrayNome.add(c);
        }
        adapterNome.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

String key = c.getKey();
Map<String, Object> postValues = c.toMap();

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put(key, postValues);

banco.updateChildren(childUpdates); // <- ESSA LINHA
```

Model (onde está o método `toMap()`):

```
public class Cidade {
    private String key;
    private String nome;
    private String passagem;
    private ArrayList<Bairro> bairro;

    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("nome", nome);
        result.put("passagem", passagem);
        result.put("bairro", bairro);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: O que é a variável `c`?

Comment: Minha classe model, `Cidade c`

Comment: O que é o método `getKey()`? Que string aparece no `key`?

Comment: `key` é a chave gerada pelo firebase ela é uma String privada, por isso tem um `get()`, editei e coloquei a parte que pega os dados do banco

Comment: @VictorStafusa esqueci de mensionar, que a variável `bairro` é uma classe

Comment: `banco.updateChildren(postValues);` no lugar de `banco.updateChildren(childUpdates);` funcionaria?

Comment: não, dá esse erro `Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type Cidade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema era que a variável `key` estava `null`, faltou atribuir a chave gerada pelo firebase